# Как написать правило редиректа для перемещенных страниц в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет. Задача такая, имеется сайт: «mysite.ru» и переместили некоторые постоянные страницы из одного каталога, в другой каталог, не важно, не все из старого каталога переехали в новый каталог, там остались какие то страницы… как написать правило редиректа, чтобы пользователи, перейдя напрямую по старому URL сразу перемещались на новые url со статусом 301?

Ниже пример задачи

**Старый каталог**

mysite.ru/cat1/page1

mysite.ru/cat1/page2

mysite.ru/cat1/page3

mysite.ru/cat1/page4

mysite.ru/cat1/page5

Теперь в новый каталог переезжают страницы “page1”, “page3”, “page5”, а остальные остаются в старом каталоге

**таким образом новый каталог**

mysite.ru/cat2/page1

mysite.ru/cat2/page3

mysite.ru/cat2/page5

Теперь эти страницы недоступны по старому адресу и на них нужно сделать 301 редирект.

Я пробовал, но у меня 1 сработал, другой не сработал,а на третий вообще выдал 404 ошибку страница не найдена…

Ps: не могу выложить код htaccess потому что пишу с телефона(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конец файла `.htaccess` добавьте так. Каждое правило с новой строки.

```
Redirect 301 /cat1/page1 /cat2/page1
Redirect 301 /cat1/page3 /cat2/page3
Redirect 301 /cat1/page5 /cat2/page5
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но у меня сработало только 1 правило, остальные 2 не работают. У меня еще сверху есть правило на убирание расширения сайта при переходе на страницы RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] может из-за этого?

Comment: Все, заработало, возможно у меня в браузере история сохранилась, с другого под инкогнито проверил, заработало!